# Тот, кто не знает пароля, на окрик часового "Стой! Кто идет?" с надеждой отвечает "Свои". Прописная или строчная?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь, цитата

**Тот, кто не знает пароля, на окрик часового "Стой! Кто идет?" с надеждой отвечает "Свои".**

- Без введения прямой речи как правильно оформить слова в кавычках? Хоть и правильнее, наверное, будет со строчной, но портится и вид предложения и восприятие: *Тот, кто не знает пароля, на окрик часового "стой! Кто идет?" с надеждой отвечает "свои".* Можно ли оставить все с прописных букв, но без двоеточия?
- И еще очень похожий вопрос. Текст: **Ведь все согласны, что "Кровь! Кровь -- великое дело". Это, кажется, Воланд говорил...** Писать его так: *Ведь все согласны, что "кровь! Кровь -- великое дело". Это, кажется, Воланд говорил...* Не может не резать глаз то, что с начала строчная, а потом прописная буква. Но и строчную букву после восклицательного знака не напишешь, тем более что в оригинале -- с прописной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правило таково:  Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится: **Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.**

Тот, кто не знает пароля, на окрик часового "Стой! Кто идет?" с надеждой отвечает: 
 "Свои".
Но обратите внимание: после слова "отвечает" следует прямая речь, поэтому нужно двоеточие. 
[Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158)

Answer (score 0):

В одном из рассказов Кафки в русском переводе встречал похожую историю. И писалось с прописной. Там было нечто вроде "... и, выдавив громкое "Эх!", он пошёл дальше..." Я к тому, что вариант с прописной и без двоеточия встречается. Это не прямая речь, да. Но мы же в кавычки берём, считайте, цитату. Значит, если цитируется начало предложения/фразы, пишется с прописной.